# How to format a Date variable in PLSQL

Tags: syntax, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL and have this question.

I created a procedure with the following specification:

```
PROCEDURE runschedule (i_RunDate  IN DATE)
```

this `i_RunDate` comes in a specific format, and I need to change it to this format:

```
'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss PM'
```

I couldn't find how to re-format a Date variable.

Comment: You may want to take a look at DBMS_Scheduler package and the Oracle concepts guide.  Folks spend a lot of money on Oracle to avoid coding their own run schedule procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DATE has not especific format, a DATE is a DATE. When stored in the database column, date values include the time of day in seconds since midnight, and a DATE variable has the same, only that when in some point you show the variable is formatted. PL/SQL can convert the datatype of a value implicitly, for example, can convert the CHAR value '02-JUN-92' to a DATE value.. but I don't recommend you rely on this implicit conversiosn. I always use the explicit conversion. 
For more on this topic, you could read this:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#i9118

In your case, if you want to format your DATE to log something, or to show in your UI or wathever in a different format, you need to assig it to a varchar variable as Justin said, something like this:

```
....
v_generated_run_date DATE; 
v_var_date VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN -- generate sysdate if required 
IF (i_RunDate is null) 
THEN 
v_var_date:=TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'); 
ELSE 
v_var_date:=TO_CHAR(i_RunDate,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'); 
END IF; 
pkgschedule.createschedule (v_var_date); 
commit; 
END runschedule; 
END
```

Your createschedule procedure, in this case, will have a varchar2 parameter...

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `TO_CHAR` function. Here's an example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thanks Justin but isn't TO_CHAR will return a VARCHAR ? I need to re-format it and leave it as a Date variable. can you please suggest something?

Comment: Can you post some code to show me how you're using it? Normally the only time you need to format a date type is when outputting it as a string so I'm a little confused as to what you're doing exactly.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkgtmschedule
AS PROCEDURE runschedule (i_RunDate IN DATE default sysdate)   IS

      v_generated_run_date DATE;
BEGIN
    -- generate sysdate if required
    IF (i_RunDate is null) THEN
                SELECT sysdate
                INTO v_generated_run_date
                FROM dual;
        ELSE
                v_generated_run_date := i_RunDate;
        END IF;
        
      pkgschedule.createschedule (v_generated_run_date);
     commit;                            
                                 
   END runschedule;


END pkgtmschedule; 
/

Comment: referring to his code above: I receive the i_RunDate as a Date, but I need to re-format it to 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' , but since it is a Date , I don't know how to re-format it. another point is when looking in the nls_session_parameters , I see that NLS_DATE_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR

Comment: What does the procedure definition look like for createschedule()? In other words, what the argument type that you are supposed to pass to it?

Comment: the procedure definition looks like : pkgschedule.createschedule (i_RunDate in DATE)

Comment: the procedure definition looks like :