# Showing data by ignoring the time portion from the date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, plsql, jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports/iReport* to do my report. I have wrote a query for the client to key in the date,but there is 1 issue, the date is come along with the time portion.

How can I ignore the time portion for the client to key in the data?

```
date                            rate
2/2/2014  12:56:21.0000 PM      ABC   
4/2/2014  12:56:21.0000 PM      EFG
5/2/2014  12:56:21.0000 PM      HIJ
...
```

I have assign from customer to design with the parameter of year,month, and day.In other words, when the customer key in the year,month,and day,
the data will show this way:

```
2/2/2014  12:56:21.0000 PM      ABC
```

The query i have wrote is show below:

```
select date,rate 
  from mytable
 where rownum=1 
       and tran_dt<=(select date 
                       from mytable 
                      where year(date)=$P{year} 
                            and month(date)=$P{month} 
                            and day(date)=$P{day}
                     )
order by 
       date
```

I'm using pl/sql query...

Comment: Why don't you simply use date(column_name) function to get only date part.

Comment: This is tagged for "plsql" which implies (to me) the use of Oracle or DB2, and also for MySQL - and the SQL appears to be for MySQL. Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**SQL SERVER :**

Use This

```
 select convert(varchar(10), '2011-02-25 21:17:33.933', 120)
```

Like This

```
 Select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d'),rate from mytable
where rownum=1 and tran_dt<=(select tran_dt from bi01_trandetail where
year(date)=$P{year} and month(tran_dt)=$P{month} and day(tran_dt)=$P{day})
order by date
```

**MYSQL**

USE

```
 DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d')


   Select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d'),rate from mytable
   where rownum=1 and tran_dt<=(select tran_dt from bi01_trandetail where
   year(date)=$P{year} and month(tran_dt)=$P{month} and day(tran_dt)=$P{day})
   order by date
```

OR

```
SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
'2003-12-31'



  Select date(date),rate from mytable
   where rownum=1 and tran_dt<=(select tran_dt from bi01_trandetail where
   year(date)=$P{year} and month(tran_dt)=$P{month} and day(tran_dt)=$P{day})
   order by date
```

Your New Query:

```
select date,rate 
  from mytable
 where rownum=1 
       and tran_dt<=(select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d') 
                       from mytable 
                      where year(date)=$P{year} 
                            and month(date)=$P{month} 
                            and day(date)=$P{day}
                     )
order by 
       date
```

[MYSQL DATE FUNCTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: Dang Satson you beat me too it!!.. This was exactly what I was going to write;

Comment: there are still error there, it show 'ORA00900' missing expression for the varchar.

Comment: @user3413288 Check My Updation

Answer (score 0):

You have to ways, from the DDBB...

**With PL/SQL** check the TO_CHAR doc, http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php, (and this SO question, ;D: [How to format a Date variable in PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515743/how-to-format-a-date-variable-in-plsql)).

Your query will be:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), rate from mytable ...
```

**With MySQL** (NOTE: I leave the MySQL answer because I answered first with it because it wasn't specified RMDB)

MySQL DATE_FORMAT function, getting only what you want: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

from the web as example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');
        -> 'Sunday October 2009'
```

Testing the case you proposed:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-03-02 23:45:35', '%e/%c/%y %H:%i:%s %p');
-> 2/3/14 23:45:35 PM
```

With no time portion:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-03-02 23:45:35', '%e/%c/%y');
-> 2/3/14
```

Your query will be:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date, '%e/%c/%y') ,rate from mytable ...
```

... and the other way is with the date functions from your server scripts, but that is another history and I'd need what language you use, XD

Comment: I am sorry that i did not stated the language before, i have just edited the...i am using pl/sql, and the query doesn't work.

Comment: ok, I leave MySQL, but for PL/SQL, check the questions I wrote you in the answer and the DATE_FORMAT and TO_CHAR function doc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the reply, i have found the way to solved this question.
Let i share the query,

select rate,trunc(date) as EFFDT from mytable
Where rownum=1
and
date <= to_date(:DAY||'/'||:MTH||'/'||:YR, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
order by date desc